# Why we need web server to run Extjs4 projects?

Tags: extjs, extjs4.2

As **Extjs4** is made with .js files then Why we need **web server** to run extjs4 project ? I read in sencha documentation that....

"You must need: A web server running locally on your computer, for example, XAMPP (Recommended)".

Can we run **extjs4** project on a local machine without installing web server (XAMPP/ Apache)? If so please tell me how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Once run the code in file system. You will get some errors or warnings in console. By seeing that errors you can understand why extjs needs webserver. :).

Comment: Do you care to accept the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Web-server needs for process http-request (listening 80 port), as is: get data(JSON/XML), refresh parts of pages and etc.

If you open index.html in browser (without web server), you need using packager (sencha command) or include the whole framework js and all your project files into your index.html, either in form of a bunch of script tags or concatenated into a single file.

Otherwise, the Loader is using XHR requests that can only be completed through a web server (security issue - imagine loading client's system files though Ajax)

Comment: Ok. i tried with static data so it works fine without web-server. But if i try to load dynamic data e.g Ext.button.Button it gives me an error as it require web server

Comment: `Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
    text: 'Click me',
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    handler: function() {
        alert('You clicked the button!');
    }
});`

Here in this case Ext.Button class needs no.of classes to be loaded

Comment: Are you using packager before run app with dynamic data?

Comment: No i am not using packager. I am a newbie so could you please tell give me how to user packager with an example?

Comment: I don't work with sencha cmd, but try this http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.0/#!/guide/command ('Introduction ...', 'Using ...', 'Creating ...').

Comment: http://existdissolve.com/2011/08/extjs-4-my-first-build/ example using Sencha SDK on all phases - create .jsb, build app-all.js...

Answer (score 0):

A Webserver is required only if you are using components which require dynamic data e.g. Grid Panel showing stock quotes. As stock quotes keep on changing, you will require a server to send the data.

You will not required webserver, if you are using static data. See DataStore Component for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Web server is not required to run any extjs code because javascript runs in browser engine and extjs is purely javascript framework. But when we think of developing an application which should be dynamic in nature(most of the apps)deployed on server so that server request/response can be handled. And in most of the cases we write business logics in server which returns some dynamic data that can be shown in UI through extjs.